# Shadow dom Input element loses focus at keyboard event

Tags: javascript, input, hotkeys, shadow-dom

I am using customized hotkeys for chrome web browser through an extension. While developing a new chrome extension myself, my text input inside a shadow dom constantly loses focus when I type the customized hotkeys. Is there anyway to make a text input inside a shadow dom not to lose focus?